# Some _instances_ of glyph disappear - how to pinpoint reason?

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, fxml

I am having a weird problem with JavaFX and Font Awesome, which I'm having trouble pin-pointing the cause of. The problem is further complicated because I can't really share the code, and no matter how much I've tried to replicate the problem in a simpler case - I couldn't.

The problem is as follows - I have a `TableView`, in which every column has a `Hyperlink` as a graphic, with a Font Awesome glyph. This all works well, except for one stage - in this stage, the first time it is shown everything is fine, but the second time three of the columns' glyphs revert to squares. This is weird, as all columns use the same glyph of the same font.

Here are before and after pictures - notice the glyphs are all the same, but the left ones become squares:

[image: First showing of stage]

[image: Second showing of stage]

The glyphs and font are set through FXML, and are the same for all columns:

```
<TableColumn fx:id="col1" prefWidth="83.0" text="Column 1"><graphic>
            <Hyperlink onAction="#requestFilter" text="" visited="true">
                <font>
                    <Font name="FontAwesome Regular" size="13.0" />
                </font></Hyperlink>
        </graphic>
</TableColumn>
<TableColumn fx:id="col2" prefWidth="138.0" text="Column 2"><graphic>
            <Hyperlink onAction="#requestFilter" text="" visited="true">
                <font>
                    <Font name="FontAwesome Regular" size="13.0" />
                </font></Hyperlink>
        </graphic>
</TableColumn>
<TableColumn fx:id="col3" prefWidth="59.0" text="Column 3"><graphic>
            <Hyperlink onAction="#requestFilter" text="" visited="true">
                <font>
                    <Font name="FontAwesome Regular" size="13.0" />
                </font></Hyperlink>
        </graphic>
</TableColumn>
<TableColumn fx:id="col4" prefWidth="103.0" text="Column 4"><graphic>
            <Hyperlink onAction="#requestFilter" text="" visited="true">
                <font>
                    <Font name="FontAwesome Regular" size="13.0" />
                </font></Hyperlink>
        </graphic>
</TableColumn>
```

Here the last two columns are the ones who lose their glyph (the scene is in right-to-left orientation).

Furthermore - it is always the last three columns that lose their glyph, that is - if on the first showing I reorder the column, the columns I leave last in the table (to the left, again - the scene is right-to-left) will lose their glyph the next time the stage is shown. Subsequent hiding/showing won't lost any more glyphs.

I show the stage with `Stage#showAndWait`, and I keep a reference to the stage, so it is only created once.

I realize it is hard to help when I can't share any code (client confidentiality), so what I'm asking is - where can I look to see what is happening? How come some instances of the same glyph disappear and others don't? Did anyone else encounter something like this? What was the underlying reason?

**Edit:** I have added debug prints of the hyperlinks' properties, and indeed with the second showing the font reverts to "System" for the last three columns. Looking for the source of the change, I have added a change listener, and put breakpoint inside it. The stack shows that the change happens inside `applyCSS`, after a lot of internal calls following `showAndWait`, non of them in my own code (i.e. - all in the JavaFX library code).  It seems for some reason JavaFX decides to reset the font definition of some of the controls, although they are all defined exactly the same!  This is corroborated by the fact that it doesn't matter which table-column it is, but where it is in the TableView.

So it seems like some erroneous JavaFX behavior is resetting the font to the default ("-fx-font") instead of the one defined on the node itself. Anyone know enough about the JavaFX CSS logic to help find the bug?
All hyperlinks have no custom styles or classes set, and only the 'visited' pseud-class set.

**Edit 2:** Adding a font name to the CSS fixes the issue. I would still love to find the source of the bug (which, I am certain, is in the JavaFX CSS handling), but it is too messy for me to go through it now. The CSS I use is:

```
.table-column .hyperlink {
    -fx-font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

Comment: Are you using [FontAwesomeFx](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) or [plain old FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/)?

Comment: Why do the TableColumns have text? Also, why do they have different prefWidths? And why all visited? Use CSS to style Controls.

Comment: Plain old FontAwesome, loaded from a ttf file included in the JAR. I can confirm it is loaded correctly, and the same behavior is observed on systems with FontAwesome installed or without it installed.

Comment: Why do they have text? Because I need them to have header text, as well as a graphic node (a custom "filter" button), and they have different prefWidths as in the real code they have different titles and generally different information displayed in them. The hyperlinks are marked visited as an easy way to have them always look the same (before or after the user clicks).  

I fail to see why CSS would be useful in this case, can you illuminate? I personally dislike having a line or two of CSS for something I can easily do in the FXML I already have.

Comment: Since you are restricted in posting more code I am trying to make sense of what code you posted. I had no luck reproducing the issue.

Comment: As to "visited". It is simply not semantically correct. I was confused by it and so could be your coworkers. You wouldn't set a Control to "disabled" just because the style should be gray. Similarly, setting "visited" might have unforeseen consequences down the line.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are correct. Conceptually it is just a button, but it needs to be styled as a plain text with a hand cursor and should have an action on click. I doubt this is related to the problem, but I'll try various other styling possibilities and report back if there's any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet that some code or css styling somewhere is changing Hyperlink font or style or css class. You can use some debugging. For example, you can add button near your TableView to print some debug information, something like this:

```
    Button b = new Button("Debug");
    b.setOnAction(e->{
        TableView<?> tv = (TableView) scene.lookup("#tableView");
        for(TableColumn<?,?> tc : tv.getColumns()) {
            Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)tc.getGraphic();
            System.out.println("Column "+tc.getText());
            System.out.println("link text: "+link.getText());
            System.out.println("link Style: "+link.getStyle());
            System.out.println("link CSS Classes: " + link.getStyleClass());
            System.out.println("link CSS Pseudo Classes: " + link.getPseudoClassStates());
            System.out.println("link Font: " + link.getFont());
        }
    });
```

Then click this button when table looks normal and save debug info somewhere. Click again when squares appear and compare the output with first one. Also inspect your css files and code that can access TableColumns, if any of those can affect Hyperlink styling.
**EDIT**
Well, it seems pretty strange to me, that JavaFX all by itself internal logic decided to recalculate and reapply css styles only for specific columns and not for the whole scene (*EDIT*: according to [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph) it actually can reapply css only on specific branches in scene graph). I still think that the root cause somewhere in your styling or code. I doubt anyone could point you to a place to look at, as it seems very specific problem and, as you said, can't be reproduced in simple scenario. Maybe you perform some specific layouting logic, recreating/replacing table nodes or somthing similar, hard to say not seeing the code.
Anyway, if you just want to solve the problem, I would suggest to set hyperlink font style in css file, not in fxml. This way you ensure that even in case of css recalculation or any layout manipulations style will be the same. It would be the right way to do it anyway.
If you want to dig up the real cause of a problem, I afraid you have to spend some happy hours with your debugger:) I would start from searching the differences between normal column and column with broken font. Why do they treated in different ways?

Comment: We seem to be getting somewhere! I'll update in the main question, as there's a lot to write.

Comment: I have triple-checked - I never remove or change any of the columns, never apply any styling to them and never change any property, either through code or through CSS. The re-applying of styles happens to all columns, it's just that for the last three the font changes.

Comment: @sillyfly Without any reproducible example any suggestion from our side would be a blind guess. Try to pinpoint the problem. Start removing all specific logic and features one by one until you find the cause. Or at least until you remove all client confidential code and would be able to show us the example:)

Comment: Well, adding a font specification to the CSS fixed it, but it is most definitely a bug in the JavaFX styling logic. I just can't be bothered to find the exact set of circumstances for it right now.

Comment: "It would be the right way to do it anyway" - I really hate this approach JavaFX seems to take - CSS should **not** be the only right way. Why do I have to have another external file if all I want is to change the font of one control? Why even give the option to change these properties through code or FXML if CSS is the only right way to do it?

Comment: Good question. But I think separating layout and styling not a bad thing after all. Specially, when FXML lack real spec (at least I couldn't find any, except some introduction doc from oracle) it is sometimes hard to say what's right or wrong doing in FXML. By the way, looking through [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph), I found that system actually can recalculate css only to specific branches in nodes graph. So it might be some node in column hierarchy causing Hyperlink css change, not taking in account value set in FXML.